# Recurring date using dayjs with dayrs-recur

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

I’m willing to create a recurring date based on "nth weekday of month"
Here is my solution work when I select current Date

```
let dates = {};
 const currentDate = dayjs();
 const recurrence = currentDate
   .recur(dayjs().add(4, "month"))
   .every("Wednesday")
   .daysOfWeek()
   .every(currentDate.monthWeekByDay())
   .weeksOfMonthByDay();
 recurrence.all().forEach((date) => {
   dates[date.format("YYYY-MM-DD")] = { selected: true, };
 });
// dates = ["2022-09-21","2022-10-19","2022-11-16","2022-12-21","2023-01-18"]
```

but if put last day of this month which is 30

```
 let dates = {};

  const lastDayofMonth = dayjs().endOf("month");
  const recurrence = lastDayofMonth
    .recur(dayjs().add(4, "month"))
    .every("Friday")
    .daysOfWeek()
    .every(lastDayofMonth.monthWeekByDay())
    .weeksOfMonthByDay();
```

I was expecting to get

```
["2022-09-30","2022-10-28","2022-11-25","2022-12-30"..]
```

instead of

```
["2022-09-30","2022-12-30"]
```

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dayjs-forked-odjikc?file=/src/index.js)

Am I missing something ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possible to create a recurring date based on "nth weekday of month" with **dayjs** and **dayjs-recur** as all months as different number of weeks

**But there are some challenges:**

- A month has 4 weeks on average (some months have few or no days for fifth week)
- Due to this there may be cases where there is no fifth week or the fifth week doesn't have the **nth weekday**

**To resolve this**

- If you are getting an **nth weekday of month** where the week is the last week of the month (could be 4th/5th week)
- Get both the **nth weekday of month** for the last week (5th) and the fourth (4th) week
- From the list of dates returned filter if dates for a month occur multiple times and select the latest/greatest one
- The filtered result should have the **nth weekday of month** where the week is the last week of the month

**Demo**

Below is a link to a working demo forked from @Achraf's demo on code sandbox

[Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dayjs-forked-4hbf04?file=/src/index.js)

**Code Example**

```
  const lastDayofMonth = dayjs().endOf("month");

  const recurrence = lastDayofMonth
    .recur(dayjs().add(4, "month"))
    .every("Friday")
    .daysOfWeek()
    .every([3, 4])
    .weeksOfMonthByDay();

  // filter recurrence
  const months = {};
  recurrence.all().forEach((date) => {
    months[date.month()] = date;
  })

  // get filtered dates
  const filteredDates = Object.values(months);

  // formot date into dates object
  filteredDates.forEach((date) => {
    dates[date.format("YYYY-MM-DD")] = { selected: true, color: "#2FB0ED" };
  });

  console.log("dates", dates);
  // ["2022-09-30","2022-10-28","2022-11-25","2022-12-30"..]
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation , but there is few thing that I don’t understand 

1- What do you mean by (no days for  fifth week ) ?
 2- some months have few ( did you mean a month can have less than 4 week ?

Comment: @Achraf some months have just 4 weeks and others 5. But in the fifth week most months have few days instead of the regular 7 days in a week